# Compiling these lines in Java - possible in any way?

Tags: java, generics, compilation, javac, error-suppression

its about compiling this method, where T is generic. Is there a way to compile this with the javac Compiler (Java 1.8) without getting any error?

```
public class MyGenericClass<T>{
    public void someGenericAction(T value){
        int key = (int) value;
    }
}
```

Best regards from Germany!

Comment: At least add info about the error you get.

Comment: Show us what are your efforts, we can then help you

Comment: java: incompatible types: T cannot be converted to int. Its just about if it is POSSIBLE to do in any way (configure the compiler ...).

Comment: you cannot convert everything to int

Comment: I would replace`<T>` with `<T extends Number>`, and `(int) value` with `value.intValue()`...

Comment: I can do like this: int key = (Integer) value;  without getting an error from the compiler.

Comment: Think about a bit how would you convert the string "xyz" into an int and what would you expect as the result. You need to restrict your type or make the interface more specific to an int

Comment: Thats not the problem. My problem is just to avoid the compiler error. Any other logical / runtime error aren't important for this question. 
But thanks for this huge amount of answers!

Comment: @MarvinKrüger you need this line "int key = (int) value;" - to execute without error by changing compiler settings?

Comment: @divine yeah thats right. Its just the question if it is possible to do that or not (using java 1.8)

Comment: @MarvinKrüger "I can do like this" compiles, but will fail at runtime. This compiles because you can cast an `Object` (the upper bound of `T`) to `Integer`; but it will fail with a `ClassCastException` when `value` isn't an `Integer`, e.g. `new MyGenericClass<String>().someGenericAction("foo");`.

Comment: @MarvinKrüger i'm intrigued.

Comment: You keep insisting on asking the question if this can be made to compile or not, regardless of whether the code makes any sense or not. If you want an answer to that question: **No**, this cannot be made to compile. It is simply not valid Java syntax and there is no way to force the compiler to accept it.

Comment: @divine I get the mentioned error "java: incompatible types: T cannot be converted to int". My question is if there is a way to ignore the error and compile this java class without changing code (f.e. set some compiler flags). I know that it dosen't make sense using this code, but my question wasn't about runtime errors.

Comment: @Jesper thanks a lot!

Comment: @MarvinKrüger see my answer

Comment: @divine thanks as well ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this

```
class MyGenericClass<T>{
        public static <T>void someGenericAction(T value){
            int key = (Integer)value; // here is your's
            System.out.println(key);
        }

        public static void main(String[] args){
            someGenericAction(12);
        }
}
```

Comment: How does this help the OP?

Comment: he just has to change his "int" to "Integer"

Comment: Thanks for answer. I have also tried this and it works. But for some reasons I have the "task" to compile the lines mentioned in my question. Just compile without getting an error, nothing else. Perhaps it's not possible but I wasn't sure about it.

Comment: @divine Yes of course, because Integer is the wrapper class and javac basically allows this. Dosen't make sense because of generic data but it will compile without error.

Comment: @MarvinKrüger did somone say to you that what you are attempting is possible?

Comment: @divine Yeah, but it was a student ;) I have to correct some tasks for university and someone have send me something like that and said it will compile ...

Answer (score 2):

I would certainly *hope* that this is impossible in Java. There's no guarantee whatsoever that any arbitrary type can be "directly" and safely typecast to an `int`, which is exactly what your method requires. In fact, for the vast majority of types, this will *not* be the case.

What does `(int)"abc"` even *mean*, for example? (That would technically be possible in the method you provide, given that `"abc"` is a perfectly valid input to your method). That cast is clearly nonsense and Java shouldn't allow it. You can come up with tons of cases like this where this cast is obvious nonsense.

It could also lead to subtle bugs in cases where it does technically work. For example, `(int)11.2` will result in rounding (it equals `11`) and, therefore, data loss.

**TL;DR** No, it's not possible, and you don't *want* it to be possible either because you're trying to do something that fundamentally doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You're essentially asking for a dirty hack: how, in general, will *any type* be coercable to an `int`?

Let's hope that `T` has a reasonable `toString` method, and exploit that:

```
int key = Integer.parseInt(value.toString());
```

This will at least compile since all objects in Java have a `toString()` method. But it's your job to handle the myriad of exceptions that could be thrown at runtime. You could add overloads to your function for other primitive types and specific types of `T` where you can do something more sensible than using the `toString()` method.

Comment: Thanks for answer but is it possible to compile my lines of code? F.e. change some compiler settings or stuff like that?

Comment: @MarvinKrüger: Hope. I think really you need to rethink your design - see the question comments. The approach I give here is "smelly".

Comment: I just wanna to know if its generally possible to compile in any way ... 
I know its absolutely not best practice, but thats not important :)

Comment: The above will compile. But using `toString()` for any kind of subsequent parsing is very bad practice.

Comment: Yeah but whats about "int key = (int) value;" ? Anything I can do to compile this line of code or is it just impossible with the javac compiler?

Comment: "I just wanna to know if its generally possible to compile in any way" No. It violates the rules in [JLS Sec 5.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5).

Comment: @AndyTurner thanks a lot. Exactly what I needed to know